# Put array into JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have an array like this in PHP:

```
$array[] = 'bob';
$array[] = 'chris';
$array[] = 'sam';
```

How would I turn it into this, in JavaScript:

```
var array = [bob, chris, sam];
```

I have tried this code but it just returns `var array = [Array];`:

```
<script>
var array = [<?php echo $array; ?>];
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use json.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
</script>
```

And then you can use it in javascript like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data)
```

Comment: I just noticed this puts `"` around the names. How do I stop this?

Comment: That is JSON format. When you parse it to javascript object " around property names will disappear.